# How can a PopUp get the styles from the main page?

Tags: 2010, web-part, popup

I have a PopUp opened by

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog
```

but the content of this Pop Up hasn't any styles of the Sharepoint Portal. (It hasn't access to javascript of the main page, too). It seems that is because SP uses iframes to open it.

How can the Pop Up get the styles from the main page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using proper master page ( MasterPageFile="~/_layouts/dialog.master") may get you the same look and feel as out of the box dialog boxes. Check out this nice article:

http://www.chaholl.com/archive/2010/11/17/using-the-dialog-framework-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx